# Azure error - wrong user password

Tags: linux, azure, azure-activedirectory, linux-on-azure

I've been trying to set up Azure domain services and a linux VM to work together, and currently I'm following the last step(joining the linux VM to the managed domain). **I try to initialize Kerberos**, using this command(ssh terminal)

`kinit bob@CANTOSO100.COM`

,with CANTOSO100.COM being my domain. Then it requires me to type in bob's password, which I **copied** when creating the user "bob". Despite of that, the ssh terminal throws this error

`kinit: Password incorrect while getting initial credentials`

Where could be the issue? Any help will be appreciated.